# Protractor: Unable to run a test

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

Am trying to run a test with protractor as specified in protractor.org. Below are the steps which I tried:

1. Prepare the spec.js and conf.js
2. Start up the se server with webdriver-manager start
3. Run the conf using the command: protactor conf.js

Issue:
An instance of the browser opens up, waits for a while and get closed.

The connection is supposed to get established to localhost:4444 as specified in the spec. But instead it tries to connect to 7055 - as indicated in the exception. Snippet of log is provided below:

```
     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
        ... 19 more
10:01:34.188 WARN - Exception: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
08198ce6fd}
```

Tried updating the webdriver-manager version, chromedriver. This issue persists in chrome, ff. Also updated the java version from 7 to 8

OS: Win 7, 64 bit, Version of chrome: 54, ff: 47

The detailed log of the standalone server is provided below:

```
C:\>webdriver-manager start
seleniumProcess.pid: 47816
09:59:14.343 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
Setting system property webdriver.chrome.driver to C:\xxx\npm\node_modules\protractor\selenium\chromedriver.exe
09:59:14.453 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.111-b14
09:59:14.453 INFO - OS: Windows 8.1 6.3 amd64
09:59:14.468 INFO - v2.47.1, with Core v2.47.1. Built from revision 411b314
09:59:14.562 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
09:59:14.562 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
09:59:14.765 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
09:59:14.765 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
10:00:45.835 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=firefox}]])
10:00:45.850 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=firefox}]
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
08198ce6fd}
1478061047473   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"{D19CA586-DD6C-4a0a-96F8-14644F340D60}","syncGUID":"LETLrz0KQvIk","location":"winreg-app-global","version":"15.
4.0","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{},"iconURL":"chrome://vscore/content/Scr
iptFF.gif","icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"McAfee ScriptScan for Firefox","description":null,"creator":"McAfee, Inc.","homepageURL":null},"visible":true,"active":false,"u
serDisabled":true,"appDisabled":true,"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\McAfee\\SystemCore","installDate":1476334281353,"updateDate":1476334281353,"applyBackgroun
dUpdates":1,"bootstrap":false,"skinnable":false,"size":3339640,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"stric
tCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"1.5","maxVersion":"9.9"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCo
mpatible":false,"signedState":0,"seen":true}
1478061047474   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1478061047474   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1478061047474   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1478061047479   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1478061047486   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1478061047486   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.0
1478061047487   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1478061047487   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.2
1478061047488   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1478061047489   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.3.2
1478061047506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1478061047506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1478061047506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1478061047506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1478061047506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1478061047506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1478061047513   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1478061047513   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1478061047513   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1478061047513   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1478061047513   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1478061047514   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1478061047842   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1478061047842   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1478061047842   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1478061047843   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1478061048095   addons.repository       DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1478061048096   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Save changes
1478061048099   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Starting timer
1478061048148   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1478061048148   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1478061048148   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1478061048151   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1478061048152   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1478061048152   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Starting write
1478061048205   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Write succeeded

        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:276)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:116)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:223)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:134)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:103)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.newInstance(DefaultDriverProvider.java:97)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
10:01:34.063 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'xxx', ip: 'xxxx', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:183)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSession.java:119)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:95)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:125)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:58)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:1)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:111)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:175)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:202)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:164)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:130)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:428)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.dispatch(ServletHandler.java:680)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:571)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1526)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1479)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:920)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
        at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:358)
        at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:537)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'xxxxxx', ip: 'xxxxx', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:113)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.newInstance(DefaultDriverProvider.java:97)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:103)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follow
s:
08198ce6fd}
1478061047473   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"{D19CA586-DD6C-4a0a-96F8-14644F340D60}","syncGUID":"LETLrz0KQvIk","location":"winreg-app-global","version":"15.
4.0","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{},"iconURL":"chrome://vscore/content/Scr
iptFF.gif","icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"McAfee ScriptScan for Firefox","description":null,"creator":"McAfee, Inc.","homepageURL":null},"visible":true,"active":false,"u
serDisabled":true,"appDisabled":true,"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\McAfee\\SystemCore","installDate":1476334281353,"updateDate":1476334281353,"applyBackgroun
dUpdates":1,"bootstrap":false,"skinnable":false,"size":3339640,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"stric
tCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"1.5","maxVersion":"9.9"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCo
mpatible":false,"signedState":0,"seen":true}
1478061047474   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1478061047474   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1478061047474   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1478061047479   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1478061047486   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1478061047486   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.0
1478061047487   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1478061047487   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.2
1478061047488   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1478061047489   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.3.2
1478061047506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1478061047506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1478061047506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1478061047506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1478061047506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1478061047506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1478061047513   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1478061047513   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1478061047513   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1478061047513   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1478061047513   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1478061047514   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1478061047842   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1478061047842   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1478061047842   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1478061047843   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1478061048095   addons.repository       DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1478061048096   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Save changes
1478061048099   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Starting timer
1478061048148   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1478061048148   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1478061048148   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1478061048151   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1478061048152   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1478061048152   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Starting write
1478061048205   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Write succeeded

Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'xxxxxx', ip 'xxxxxx', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:134)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:276)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:116)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:223)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:134)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
08198ce6fd}
1478061047473   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"{D19CA586-DD6C-4a0a-96F8-14644F340D60}","syncGUID":"LETLrz0KQvIk","location":"winreg-app-global","version":"15.
4.0","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{},"iconURL":"chrome://vscore/content/Scr
iptFF.gif","icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"McAfee ScriptScan for Firefox","description":null,"creator":"McAfee, Inc.","homepageURL":null},"visible":true,"active":false,"u
serDisabled":true,"appDisabled":true,"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\McAfee\\SystemCore","installDate":1476334281353,"updateDate":1476334281353,"applyBackgroun
dUpdates":1,"bootstrap":false,"skinnable":false,"size":3339640,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"stric
tCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"1.5","maxVersion":"9.9"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCo
mpatible":false,"signedState":0,"seen":true}
1478061047474   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1478061047474   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1478061047474   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1478061047479   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1478061047486   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1478061047486   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.0
1478061047487   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1478061047487   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.2
1478061047488   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1478061047489   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.3.2
1478061047506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1478061047506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1478061047506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1478061047506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1478061047506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1478061047506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1478061047513   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1478061047513   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1478061047513   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1478061047513   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1478061047513   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1478061047514   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1478061047842   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1478061047842   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1478061047842   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1478061047843   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1478061048095   addons.repository       DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1478061048096   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Save changes
1478061048099   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Starting timer
1478061048148   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1478061048148   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1478061048148   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1478061048151   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1478061048152   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1478061048152   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Starting write
1478061048205   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Write succeeded

        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
        ... 19 more
10:01:34.188 WARN - Exception: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
08198ce6fd}
1478061047473   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"{D19CA586-DD6C-4a0a-96F8-14644F340D60}","syncGUID":"LETLrz0KQvIk","location":"winreg-app-global","version":"15.
4.0","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{},"iconURL":"chrome://vscore/content/Scr
iptFF.gif","icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"McAfee ScriptScan for Firefox","description":null,"creator":"McAfee, Inc.","homepageURL":null},"visible":true,"active":false,"u
serDisabled":true,"appDisabled":true,"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\McAfee\\SystemCore","installDate":1476334281353,"updateDate":1476334281353,"applyBackgroun
dUpdates":1,"bootstrap":false,"skinnable":false,"size":3339640,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"stric
tCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"1.5","maxVersion":"9.9"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCo
mpatible":false,"signedState":0,"seen":true}
1478061047474   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1478061047474   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1478061047474   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1478061047479   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1478061047486   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1478061047486   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.0
1478061047487   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1478061047487   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.2
1478061047488   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1478061047489   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.3.2
1478061047506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1478061047506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1478061047506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1478061047506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1478061047506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1478061047506   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1478061047513   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1478061047513   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1478061047513   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1478061047513   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1478061047513   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1478061047514   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1478061047842   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1478061047842   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1478061047842   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1478061047843   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1478061048095   addons.repository       DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1478061048096   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Save changes
1478061048099   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Starting timer
1478061048148   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1478061048148   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1478061048148   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1478061048151   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1478061048152   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1478061048152   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Starting write
1478061048205   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Write succeeded
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried the same on another machine. It worked as expected.

Windows Server 2008
Java version - 1.7.0_79-b15
chrome version - 54
webdriver version 2.53